# How to combine deferreds / promises in an "AND" relationship, but don't count a single reject as an overall reject?

Tags: javascript, promise, angular-promise, jquery-deferred, deferred

Short question is: for multiple concurrent promises, how to make something happen at the end after all promises either succeeded or failed? (instead of doing something right after 1 promise failed).

I think it applies to both jQuery Deferreds or AngularJS Deferreds, and the requirement is, let's say there are 16 square panel on the screen laid out as a 4 x 4 grid.

A user can click "fetch" or "refresh" to refresh each square panel, and the data will be fetched for that particular panel.

So it is a simple Promise situation: 16 promises.

However, what if a global "spinning wheel" is needed, say, at the top right corner of the viewport.  It will show itself whenever even a single square panel is waiting for data, and likewise if 2, or 3, or more panels are waiting for data.  The spinning wheel should go away when all data fetching have either succeeded or failed.  But the keypoint is, when a single data fetch failed, it should not consider the whole overall operation failed and immediately hide the spinning wheel.

Is there a way to use `$.when()` or `$.pipe()` to do the job?  `$.when()` seems like an "AND" relationship, but any single failed fetching will make the operation considered to be totally failed and hide the spinning wheel immediately.  Can we use `$.when()` as a new promise and therefore somehow to use it to report "progress"? (but how?).  (actually, if `when()` can return a promise that can be observed for progress, with data `{ total: 8, success: 3, fail: 1, pending: 4 }`, then it may work for what is exactly needed.  We just need to show or hide the spinning wheel depending on whether `pending` is `0`, and that's really simple.

A simple way that will work is just to have a counter for the number of "active" square panel.  When each panel start data fetching, increment the counter, and upon fetching succeed or fail, then decrement the counter, but that may be not so clean if it is a global variable floating around.

Another way may be to build an overallPanel object, and it "has" (meaning composition) 16 squarePanel objects, and each squarePanel will need to be an observable object itself, so that the overallPanel will observe on each, and increment or decrement a counter, and show spinning wheel when counter > 0, and hide when counter == 0.  (So when each squarePanel either succeeded or failed for fetching the data, it will in turn resolve or reject itself so as to notify the observer, which is the overallPanel)

Or is there a way to use the built-in Promise or Deferred function?

Comment: A mediator sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 2):

Well, like you said, you have `$.when` and `$q.all` which are both effectively `Promise.all` from native (and bluebird) promises.

What you're missing is a `reflect` primitive that converts rejections to fulfillments and indicates the said failure in some way:

```
var res = Promise.all(promises.map(x => x.then(v => ({v, good: true}), 
                                               e => ({e, bad: true})));
```

Which would let you do:

```
res.then(results => {
   let good = results.filter(x => x.good);
   let bad = results.filter(x => x.bad);
});
```

And work with both good and bad results. No need to implement your own logic for counting promises.

Comment: nice, but shouldn't you also extract `v` from the results into `good` instead of the entire `{v, good: true}` object?  (and likewise for `e` into `bad`)

Comment: hm... that is, if we can put everything into a `when()` to begin with.  What if the user can click this, and after 2 seconds, click that (on the squarePanel), so the promises are dynamically added to the "total task" (and dynamically finished, and can yet again be dynamically added while other promises are still pending)

Comment: @太極者無極而生 that's an entirely different task (dynamic number of promises - when would you know there aren't any to add? Different question entirely.)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum is it true that by the nature of a promise, once it is resolved or rejected, then there is no turning back. So in a way, you really can't combine multiple promises into one promise this way, because, if you have 2 promises that both became non-pending, well, then, you can't really re-use that existing overall promise, because it was resolved and there is no turning back... unless if we instantiate another overall promise.  Isn't it true that if we have a dynamic version of `when()`, such as `when_dynamic()` that can allow dynamically adding of promises, then it will work?

Comment: What you said is correct - you just wouldn't use promises for this task.